# What does 'data()' do in '$("#myWidget").data(`ejTE`)'

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
var editor = $("#htmlEditor").data('ejRTE');
```

The question is what does `.data('ejRTE')` do?

It retrieves the widget which is part of this html:

```
<textarea id="htmlEditor" value.bind="entity.content"
                  ej-rte="e-width:100%"
                  ref="textArea"
                  style="height: 220px"></textarea>
```

How do I retrieve it without jQuery.

Comment: Try `$("#htmlEditor").data();` to get all the `data-*` properties associated with `Element`\

Comment: I was trying to see how I could retrieve without jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jQuery.data() Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or
>   return the value that was set.

So basically the widget stores some data in the element `htmlEditor` indexed `ejRTE`, I bet it is a custom object used by this tool.

```
var editor = $("#htmlEditor").data('ejRTE');
```

then `editor` will hold the object stored by the widget for this element

Comment: No, it's not stored in the dataset. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you set data like this `$(#myWidget).data('foo', 'myFoo')` then jQuery will create an object called 'jQuery224059863907884721222' on `myWidget` which it uses to store the value.

I am guessing that the number is an arbitrary datetime value.

I stepped through the jQuery code, and it's not practical to replace it. I thought it might be just a line or two of code.

Comment: sounds good, I was not totally sure that it is saved in `dataset`, its cleared out now, thanks..

Comment: hmm , interesting thanks for the info..will dig into deep